# PostgreSQL range query index

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-indexes

Let's say I have a simple table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE bingest.some_data (
      report_date DATE NOT NULL,
      client_id UUID NOT NULL,
      value_1 INT, value_2 INT, value_3 INT,
      value_4 INT, value_5 INT, value_6 INT,
      value_7 INT, value_8 INT, value_9 INT,
      value_10 INT, value_11 INT, value_12 INT,
      value_13 INT, value_14 INT, value_15 INT,
      value_16 INT, value_17 INT, value_18 INT,
      value_19 INT,
PRIMARY KEY (report_date, client_id));
```

I want to have the index used in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM some_data WHERE report_date > '2018-10-30';
```

For the above query the **EXPLAIN** command gives me this

```
Seq Scan on some_data  (cost=0.00..18.12 rows=217 width=96)
    Filter: (report_date > '2018-10-30'::date)
Planning time: 0.061 ms
Execution time: 0.019 ms
```

The index is used when I specify upper and lower bounds

```
SELECT * FROM some_data WHERE report_date > '2018-10-30' AND < '2019-10-30'
```

For this one **EXPLAIN** gives the following output:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on some_data  (cost=4.18..11.30 rows=3 width=96)
    Recheck Cond: ((report_date > '2018-10-30'::date) AND (report_date < '2019-10-30'::date))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on some_data_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: ((report_date > '2018-10-30'::date) AND (report_date < '2019-10-30'::date))
Planning time: 0.072 ms
Execution time: 0.027 ms
```

I do not have any data yet but I want to prepare right indexes for this table.

Comment: How many rows does the table contain? And could you add the `explain (analyze, buffers)` output for the first query as well please?

Comment: There are no rows yet, I'm preparing to bulk load data into this table but want to have correct indexes in place first. Would it make a difference for the first query plan if there were some rows in the table ?

Comment: It's probably not worth it to use the index in the first query.  The selectivity of the query needs to be fairly low (like 3-5% of the table or something like that) for postgres to choose to use the index.  You can try temporarily disabling sequential scan with set enable_seqscan = off; to see what the results look like when forcing it to use the index

Comment: if there's no rows then it'll always be better to do a sequential scan

Comment: If the table is empty it doesn't matter which execution plan Postgres uses. Do not test performance with just a few rows. Always check the performance with a realistic number of rows that match your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If a table is completely empty, PostgreSQL estimates that it contains 10 pages (see `estimate_rel_size` in `src/backend/optimizer/util/plancat.c`).

This so that we don't get disastrous underestimates if a table contains a few rows and has not been autovacuumed yet.

The upshot is that the estimates for an empty table are completely bogus, and your observations don't mean anything.

To test if an index **can be used**, set `enable_seqscan` to off and explain the query. If it still chooses the expensive sequential scan, it does so because it cannot use the index.

Answer (score 0):

With an empty table, any discussion of performance tuning is theoretical.  To really know anything for sure, you need to put lots of data in the table and have that data be as realistic of a production data set that you can reasonably come up with.

That said, onto the theory...

**Table scans versus index**

With an empty table, the most efficient execution plan would generally be a full table scan.  Why?  The startup cost / overhead of a full is very low.

Index usage has high overhead (meaning, the baseline cost of simply searching it regardless of what is found), but an extremely low per-row cost.  Full table scans have extremely low overhead, with the maximum per-row cost.  With that said, there are two rules of thumb:

- The smaller the table, the less useful an index is.
- The more *selective* an index search is, the more useful it is.  Searching an index to then match 90% of the rows in the table is very inefficient and RDBMS's are generally smart enough to not do that.

**Estimates & Statistics**

Given the above rules of thumb, for an RDBMS to decide which plan is the most efficient, it needs to know some details of the data, specifically, the number of rows in the table, and the number of rows a query is likely to match.

We get a catch-22 because it needs to query the data to find out how much data will come back, so that it can pick the most efficient query plan.

So the way this all works is that RDBMS's like Postgres store statistics about the data for the query planner to use.  These statistics are accurate at particular points in time and they are estimates.  Example statistics:

1. Approximate row count for table
2. For an index, approximate row count for each key
3. Frequency of particular values in a column

Again, remember that these are estimates.  For Postgres to guarantee statistics are perfectly precise at all times is very expensive, but we don't need high precision for choosing an execution plan.  The difference between a 1-row table and a 2-row table is inconsequential.  But a 1-row table versus a thousand-row table or million-row table matters a lot.

Some good reading here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/planner-stats.html

**Summary**

With all that said, Postgres is likely not sure exactly how many rows are in your table, but knows it's small.  Therefore, the threshold for when to use an index is high, hence your first query does a table scan.  With the second date check, it is likely figuring the query will match a smaller number of rows when it checks the primary key index, so it goes for the index.